# How do I calculate n averages over a datetime range?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an application that samples data every 15 seconds from several (right now 48) different data points. These data points are represented in a table by two different foreign keys (MeasurementTypeId and GeneratorId), a sample value (Value) and a datetime (MeasurementDate).

So, the table looks like this (I'm only including 10 rows and only a few different foreign key combinations)

```
+------+-------------------+-------------+-------+------------------------+
|  ID  | MeasurementTypeId | GeneratorId | Value | MeasurementDate        |
+------+-------------------+-------------+-------+------------------------+
|    1 |       PSI         |     SG-52   |  0.19 |   2013-08-27 09:19:30  |
|    2 |       PH          |     SG-52   |  6.39 |   2013-08-27 09:19:30  |
|    3 |       DEG         |     SG-52   | 90.85 |   2013-08-27 09:19:30  |
|    4 |       PSI         |     PT-14   |  0.33 |   2013-08-27 09:19:30  |
|    5 |       PH          |     PT-14   |  6.41 |   2013-08-27 09:19:30  |
|    6 |       DEG         |     PT-14   | 89.20 |   2013-08-27 09:19:30  |
|    7 |       PSI         |     SG-52   |  0.20 |   2013-08-27 09:19:45  |
|    8 |       PH          |     SG-52   |  6.37 |   2013-08-27 09:19:45  |
|    9 |       DEG         |     SG-52   | 90.84 |   2013-08-27 09:19:45  |
|   10 |       PSI         |     PT-14   |  0.34 |   2013-08-27 09:19:45  |
+------+-------------------+-------------+-------+------------------------+
```

I'm looking to create a stored procedure that can return the average values (grouped by the foreign keys) for an interval over a datetime range. However, I don't want to define the interval, rather leave that up to the user invoking the stored procedure.

I would like the stored procedure to take parameters of

```
@numberOfIntervals int,
@startDateRange datetime,
@endDateRange datetime
```

And divide the datediff of the startDateRange and endDateRange by the numberOfIntervals to determine the interval over which to do the average.

For example if the procedure is invoked with 3, '2013-08-26 00:00:00', '2013-08-27 00:00:00'

The results would be 3 records for each group by combination with the value equal to the average of the 8 hours interval (only 10 results included for brevity...Actual results would include 18)

```
+-------------------+-------------+-------+------------------------+
| MeasurementTypeId | GeneratorId | Value | MeasurementDate        |
+-------------------+-------------+-------+------------------------+
|       PSI         |     SG-52   |  0.20 |   2013-08-26 08:00:00  |
|       PH          |     SG-52   |  7.11 |   2013-08-26 08:00:00  |
|       DEG         |     SG-52   | 90.02 |   2013-08-26 08:00:00  |
|       PSI         |     PT-14   |  0.44 |   2013-08-26 08:00:00  |
|       PH          |     PT-14   |  6.98 |   2013-08-26 08:00:00  |
|       DEG         |     PT-14   | 90.31 |   2013-08-26 08:00:00  |
|       PSI         |     SG-52   |  0.21 |   2013-08-26 16:00:00  |
|       PH          |     SG-52   |  7.12 |   2013-08-26 16:00:00  |
|       DEG         |     SG-52   | 90.01 |   2013-08-26 16:00:00  |
|       PSI         |     PT-14   |  0.44 |   2013-08-26 16:00:00  |
+-------------------+-------------+-------+------------------------+
```

I have done some work to calculate the moving averages, but that is for a specific time frame and a specific number of intervals. With this, I want the user to be able to select a daterange and a specified number of intervals and graph the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a CTE to get the intervals to group by

```
DECLARE @numberOfIntervals INT = 3
DECLARE @startDateRange DATETIME = '2013-08-27'
DECLARE @endDateRange DATETIME = '2013-08-28'

--

DECLARE @range INT = DATEDIFF(HH, @startDateRange, @endDateRange) / @numberOfIntervals

;WITH calendar AS
(
  SELECT @startDateRange StartDate, DATEADD(HH, @range, @startDateRange) EndDate
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DATEADD(HH, @range, StartDate), DATEADD(HH, @range, EndDate)
  FROM calendar
  WHERE DATEADD(HH, @range, StartDate) < @endDateRange
)

SELECT MeasurementTypeId, 
       GeneratorId, 
       StartDate AS MeasurementDateStart,
       AVG(Value) AverageValue
FROM (
    SELECT d.*, c.StartDate
    FROM data d
    JOIN calendar c
      ON d.MeasurementDate >= c.StartDate
     AND d.MeasurementDate < c.EndDate
) sub
GROUP BY MeasurementTypeId, GeneratorId, StartDate
```

[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fd100/1)

what you'd probably want to add is handling `@numberOfIntervals` that don't divide nicely, adding minutes instead of hours if `@numberOfIntervals` is greater than 24 etc.

Comment: Perfect.  I modified it to go off of the minutes (mi) and added an order by MeasurementTypeId, GeneratorId, StartDate just to see the results more clearly. Over a three hour sample of 30,000 rows it worked well.  Is there a way to make it more efficient? Speed will be a key factor.